# How to get reference from a element that is not in the same tree of nodes of the element that hold the state?

Tags: reactjs, reference, framer-motion

I am using framer-motion, and i have three main components: NavBar (which is multiple), main(outlet), and footer:
I got a listener in the NavBar tracking the scroll behavior, to change the header. ALL PERFECT.
The problem comes when I need to pass this value to the outlet to move it with the NavBar.
Here is my Layout structure:

```
export default function Layout() {
    return (
        <EzStackMui sx={{minHeight: '100vh', position: 'relative'}} id='layout'>
            {/*top bar*/}
            <NavBar/>
            <>
                <EzStackMui
                    sx={{
                        flex: 1,
                        // minHeight: '100vh'
                    }}
                    id='outlet'
                    component='main'
                >
                    <Outlet/>
                </EzStackMui>
            </>

            {/*footer*/}
            <Footer/>
        </EzStackMui>
    );
}
```

```
//keep track of scrolling
    const [isScroll, setIsScroll] = useState(0)
    const {scrollY} = useScroll()
    useMotionValueEvent(scrollY, "change", (latest) => {
        let outlet = document.getElementById('outlet')
        outlet.style.marginTop = latest >= 100 ? '20px' : null
        setIsScroll(latest)
    })
```

I tried: to get the reference by id but it couldn't be animated with motion and it is not a good pattern to get an element like that in react.

```
let outlet = document.getLementById('outlet')
outlet.style.marginTop = latest >= 100 ? '20px' : null
```

I think of keeping the value in the redux store but that is going to be overkill the app updating constantly the store.

Comment: Where is this "keep track of scrolling" code?

Comment: literally the second code said: //keep track of scrolling. using the useScroll() hook to keep track and useMotionValueEvent() to update it. Both comes from framer-motion

Comment: I was asking *where* is this code, as in which file. You say "header" but it's unclear where is your header.

Comment: I updated it. NavBar